# How did Picard send a binary message to Data in the future?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

In the Star Trek TNG episode ["Times Arrow", parts one](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Time%27s_Arrow_%28episode%29) and [two](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Time%27s_Arrow,_Part_II_(episode)), recall the following:

- Data's head was found in an excavation on Earth that dates from the 19th century (it actually *is* Data's head).
- Data, Picard, Crusher, Worf, and others go back in time to the 19th century to investigate.
- Guinan (her 500-year younger self) was living in San Francisco in the 19th century.
- This is where Guinan first meets Picard, but not where Picard first meets Guinan.
- It turns out that alien time travelers are sucking energy out of people on Earth from the 19th century.
- In the process, Data is caught in an altercation which essentially blows his head off.

Here's where things get especially interesting...

- In an effort to stop these aliens, all of the away team along with Samuel Clemens, **except Picard** and Guinan end up back in the future to try to destroy the aliens time travel site on their planet.
- Picard, still in the 19th century finds out from one of the aliens that if the Enterprise in the future fires upon the alien time travel site, the energy from the ship's phasers will only serve to increase the aliens' power.
- Commander LaForge manages to reassemble the 500 year old Data head, after removing a suspicious piece of metal lodged in one of Data's cranial ports. "How did that get in there?" LaForge asks.
- We are then taken back in time to see Picard is responsible for putting the metal piece in there. He also enters a binary message into Data's static memory warning the Enterprise not to fire on the alien site.
- Data (reassembled) receives this message, and the crew make a plan to destroy the alien site by making a tweak to the ship's weapons.
- Before destroying the site, Samuel Clemens goes back in time and allows Picard to return to the 24th century

Everybody wins! What an awesome episode!

### But here's the rub

From Picard's perspective, he simply entered the binary message into Data's head, and then was immediately rescued. I should think that Picard would have had to have lived a lifetime in the 19th century, then died, and then 500 years later, Data's head would be found. At this point, the static memory in Data's head warning the Enterprise would be there legitimately and the episode could continue as normal.

So how does entering the binary message into Data's static memory seemingly transcend the space time continuum and make it to the future?

Comment: its loops and alternate timelines and general timetravel bullshit, but to me, essentially yes picard would die they would find data fix him find out where picard was, and then go get him from that exact time he imputed the code into data, aka, its an infinate loop, paradox.

Comment: I hate temporal mechanics...

Comment: Because Data's head exists in both places and at both times. By making a change to his head in 1800, the change is visible in 2300. Picard doesn't need to live and die in the 1800s since he's already created an exit point.

Comment: @Richard, that is like "Back to the Future" logic, where a change in the past starts making things disappear in the future. Which would mean every point in the space-time continuum is connected infinitely to every other point in the continuum.... which is a headache and not very intellectually satisfying.

Comment: @matrixugly Not if we assume that *Time's Arrow* is a stable time loop, which we have no evidence to refute (not from my admittedly hazy recollection, at least)

Comment: @matrixugly - No, Geordi only discovers the shard when the head is being thoroughly examined. That doesn't mean that it wasn't in there the whole time. Picard would have been aware that **the examination hadn't taken place before he left the ship** meaning that any internal changes he makes to Data's head wouldn't be discovered until later. That makes it the perfect tool to communicate with the future.

Comment: @Richard - Well we know that Picard put the shard there and inputted the data. 19th century Picard should have continued some sort of existence there until his death. Then when Data's head was found, the shard could legitimately be there the whole time. Once Geordi reassembles Data, they can go back and rescue Picard. Then this Picard can live in the 24th century until his death.

Comment: Yes, except that that continued existence (the alternate timeline where picard lived and died in the 19th century) never happened. Or rather it un-happened.

Comment: @matrixugly - You seem to be assuming a model in which each trip back to the past spawns a new timeline, so for any given instance where travelers arrive from the future, there must have been an "original" timeline where those particular travelers did *not* arrive from the future. But Star Trek is rather inconsistent about how time travel works, and some stories seem to take place in a single self-consistent timeline. We could speculate that this depends on the type of physical mechanism used to enable time travel, I suppose...

Comment: Haha, yes, it makes 19th century Picard's life irrelevant in a stable time loop. I suppose these kinds of questions always lead to some sort of assumption that a critical paradox is ignored.

Comment: For shows like Star Trek and Doctor Who that seem to feature inconsistent rules of time travel, I like to imagine a notion of multiple interacting timelines which are all *mutually* self-consistent, so for example traveling back from timeline A could take you to a nearly identical timeline B, and then when the version of you in timeline B travels back on the same date, he ends up in timeline A. But in other cases you could have mutually self-consistent interactions between two (or more) timelines A and B that are very different. This way, both types of stories can coexist.

Comment: I like the suggestion that Richard made - where Picard's alternate timeline in the 19th century happened, then "un"-happened, making it irrelevant. @Richard, if you formalize that in an answer, I'll go with that one.

Comment: Try simplifying it. You go back in time and bring with you a device onto which you record a message. You hide it where the chances of it being found are practically zero. You then go forward to *now* and pick up the device. Do you think the message will still be there?

Comment: @SixthOfFour - But the question isn't really about whether the message would still be there in the future, it's about whether, when the Enterprise crew finds it in the future and open the rift again so Samuel Clemens can return home and Picard can come back to the 24th century, they are creating an altered timeline (meaning there was some original timeline where Clemens didn't appear from the future and Picard just had to live out his life in the past) or whether it all happens in a single self-consistent timeline.

Comment: @Hypnosifl By extension it's the same question. If you were stranded in the past and a friend of yours found the device by accident, (s)he could act on it and rescue you, so you wouldn't have to live out your days in the past.

Comment: @SixthOfFour - But a common model of time travel in fiction is that each time you travel into the past, you spawn a new parallel timeline, without negating the existence of the "original" timeline where you *didn't* appear in the past--the two timelines are identical up until the moment that you do/don't appear in the past, then they can diverge. If you go with this model, then if your friend comes back in time to rescue you there will be two timelines, one where your friend appears from the future to rescue you and one where they don't.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I quite happily entertain the idea of multiple timelines as a very real thing. My idea about it is that every single time you make a choice, each possible alternative is played out in a separate timeline. Multiply that by every choice every living thing has ever made and will ever make. And by that view, Picard did live and die in the 19th century. Several "copies" of him, each one in its own timeline. He also went forward to the 24th. Perhaps that is what the OP has a problem with, and then I cannot explain it much better.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I really do think of the world like that. And for lack of a better word (English isn't my native language, so there may be one of which I'm not aware; I'm considering "event", but I don't feel that it's significantly better) I use the word "choice" in an extremely broad sense, including non-sentient choices like in which direction a branch of a tree splits, and completely random things, such as which pebble you happen to kick when you take a step.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Welcome to the Grandfather Paradox. Start with the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox).

There are at least four ways to handle this:

1. Picard's actions form a self-determining loop. That is, the origins of his actions are contained entirely with the loop. The classic along these lines is Heinlein's [**All You Zombies**](http://cla.calpoly.edu/~lcall/303/heinlein_all_you_zombies.pdf).
2. When Picard altered Data's memory, he created a parallel universe (timeline) in which the data exists/existed/will exist. When the team returned from the past, they entered this new timeline. In the old timeline, they never returned.
3. When Picard altered Data's memory, he created a history which overwrote the original history which caused him to go back in time. The original history, in which Data's memory was not modified, ceases to "exist", as far as the word applies.
4. There's no problem. The away team went back in time without having performed a detailed examination of Data's head. So it had always been modified, and Picard's actions had always occurred. Again, as far as the word "always" applies.

An excellent discussion of the peculiarities of time travel (from a purely speculative viewpoint, of course) is Larry Niven's [**The Theory and Practice of Time Travel**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0xb4crOvCgTQVg5NDhObjRpNUE/edit?pli=1)

Comment: [This page](http://qntm.org/models) and [this one](http://www.xibalba.demon.co.uk/jbr/chrono.html) are also good for those interested in discussion of different fictional models of time travel.

Comment: More information on option number one can be found under [Novikov self-consistency principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle)

Comment: For a story-telling point of view, option #2 isn't satisfying, because this means that the villains always wind up winning (in some timeline).

Comment: @Michael - In some cases that is very satisfying.

Comment: It's #4. 
All of the content in the episode already happened before the enterprise started sending people into the past.  Guinan has a knowledge of all of these events and knows Picard will make it back. 
"If you don't go, we'll never meet."
Also, Data's head was found before they sent anyone back in time with damage that lines up exactly with the body they later recovered.  This is additional proof that the events always played out this way in the past before the episode began.

Comment: @Kalamane - Sorry, but every option allows for Guinan's behavior. #1, for instance, works if Guinan is actually a time-traveller who has jumped from after the loop to before. #2 can be explained by Guinan having meta-awareness of the two timelines. Since Guinan is a complete enigma, with no backstory presented, both of these are possible. On several occasions she makes pronouncements as to how the future will unfold, and these are economically explained by time travel.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: See also Guinan's memory of the "correct" timeline in "Yesterday's Enterprise."

Answer (score 12):

Data's head begins life with Data's body. At some point, the whole body goes back in time. The head is severed and left behind. Picard (also left behind) plays with it to encode a message. Picard is retrieved by his colleagues in the future. 500 years later, the head is found again and brought back on board the Enterprise. It's plugged back into the body (which took a "shortcut" by not being left behind). Data relays the message, and the crew retrieve Picard.

There's only one path that the head took. It can be a little difficult to get your head around (lol) simply because (from his perspective) Picard was rescued centuries before his SOS message would be received, and because Data's head and body got back to the 24th Century via extremely different means. The head took the long way around. But Picard's fiddling with it didn't need to create an alternate timeline, or bypass a paradox, or make Picard wait (?) or anything like that. It was simply a man playing with his buddy's head.

```
            olden days                     23rd century       
t ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════→

    Guinan ┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄→

    Clements ┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄ †
                                       Data  Team (ex. Data)
                                         ↓      ↓
       ╭─────────────────────────────────╯      │
       │   ╭────────────────────────────────────╯
       ↓   │
       ¦   ↓
       ¦   ╰┄ Team (ex. Picard)
       ¦        ¦
       ¦        ╰───────────────────────────────────∎┄┄┄┄╮
       ¦                                                 ↓
       ╰┄┄┄┄→ Data's body                                ¦
                ↓                                        ¦
                ├───────────────────────────────────∎┄┄┄┄┤
                ¦                                        ¦
              Data's                                     ¦
            head (with message)                          ¦
                ¦                                        ¦
                ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄⁕┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄⁕
                ¦             Head discovered            ¦
                ¦                               Data recombined
                ¦                                Msg discovered
             Picard                                      ¦
                ¦                                        ╰┄╮
                ╰┄┄┄╮                                      ¦
                    ¦                                      ¦
                    ¦                                  Rescue
                    ¦                                   team
                    ¦                                      ↓
                    ¦ ╭────────────────────────────────────╯
                    ¦ │
                    ¦ │
                    ¦ │
                    ╰┄↓
                    Picard and
                    rescue team
                         │
                         ╰───────────────────────────────────∎┄┄┄→
```

Where solid lines (─) indicate unnatural time travel, and dotted lines (┄) indicate the more conventional way of simply sitting there until years have passed. Rightwards is absolute chronology; downwards is subjective chronology (i.e. events in the order portrayed in the episode and experienced by the characters).

You can see that Data's head, message an' all, just makes it to the future in the usual manner. Picard and the rescue team *and Data's body* are jumping around all over the place, making it more confusing, but the head is the *one* part of the puzzle that can't possibly cause anything more than the predestination paradox incited by its being found in the 23rd Century right as the episode's narrative begins.

The key salient point is that Data's head was *always* there, in San Francisco, with a message encoded in it. Since the beginning of the series, and since way before that. It's just that we (and the crew) didn't know that until the events of this episode (which ironically caused the whole issue in the first place!).

> I should think that Picard would have had to have lived a lifetime in the 19th century, then died, and then 500 years later, Data's head would be found.

*That* would be a paradox. Picard did a thing. That thing had an effect: his crewmates obtaining that information. That he was rescued immediately thereafter is an effect of their time travelling. If he somehow also experienced a timeline in which he just sat there for years because his message had not got through and his crewmates no longer decided to go back in time to rescue him, then *that* would be a problem.

> So how does entering the binary message into Data's static memory seemingly transcend the space time continuum and make it to the future?

When you write a message on a piece of paper, it's still there the next day. That's the normal flow of information through the passage of time. Presumably you are not transcending the space-time continuum in order to allow your message to make it to the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

picard doesn't have to live a life in the past, he only has to have placed his butterfly for events to continue to unfold as they should. Once the message is received in the future, and the aliens are stopped, picard can go back to the future at any time. The artifacts of being in the past, although lucky to have made it as far as that point in the future are already predetermined as a past event from picard's perspective. I.e. he already knew they found data's head and thus the vehicle for his message to the future was secured.