# Why did Picard leave the iron filing inside of Data's head?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

When writing [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110056/19252), I was reminded of something in a scene of [Time's Arrow Part 2](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/227.htm) that I find to be odd.

Picard encodes a binary message for the Enterprise crew inside of Data's head, which was, err, "forcibly detached" sometime in the past in San Francisco. He then also places the iron filing inside of Data's head. This results in LaForge encountering issues when trying to reboot Data after he takes Data's recovered head and reattaches it to Data's body after his head is "forcibly detached" when most of the away team returns to their normal time. (for those confused, please watch the episode - time travel is complicated)

Why did Picard include the iron filing inside of Data's head after he finished encoding his message?

Comment: My reading was that it was supposed to prevent Geordi from *immediately* rebooting Data (which would have been the wrong time), thus forcing him to take the head up to the ship for a diagnostic and thus giving Picard time to travel back through the rift.

Comment: "For those confused" you can read the series of events at [How did Picard send a binary message to Data in the future?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/82418)

Comment: My comment seems [apt](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82418/how-did-picard-send-a-binary-message-to-data-in-the-future#comment176759_82418)

Comment: @Richard: Did they ever try to activate Data's head after they found it? I don't recall them attempting it when watching the episode and I can't find any mention of it in the script. If not, doesn't adding the filing there to prevent preemptive activation seem moot when Picard probably should have known they did not attempt to activate it before the entire senior staff was in the past with him?

Comment: @Ellesedil - No, but we know his head can function independently. I find it unlikely that Geordi didn't at least try flicking the on-button to see what would happen.

Comment: He left it in, because he left it in?  Didn't he already know it was going to be there?

Comment: @Zoredache: I don't think so. LaForge is the only one that ended up discovering it, and he didn't discover it until the rest of the senior staff returned to their own time and began formulating what they were going to do about the situation while Picard was still in the past.

Comment: Out of universe, is it *possibly* a reference to [Luke finding Leia's message only because R2-D2 was jammed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFrDg2BOXOM)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters we should point out that (<sup><sub>Past</sub></sup>)Picard didn't use the iron filing to create the message, he used a [small nail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fYfb.png) that he found on the floor of the cavern. That means that his intention in leaving the iron filing inside Data's head, **in a place that prevented him from being booted up**  *must have been* to prevent Data from being activated until the appropriate time.

### So what would have happened if the iron filing *wasn't there*?

We know from an earlier episode in the season (TNG: [Disaster](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/205.txt)) that [Data's head can function perfectly well without his body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tIhm.png). Had (<sup><sub>Past</sub></sup>)Picard not blocked Data's bootup sequence, La Forge could have brought him back to consciousness shortly *before* the ship arrived at Devidia 2 and *before* Picard and crew had beamed down to the surface.

Faced with the knowledge of how to destroy the alien's portal and the inherent risk of trying to fight against an opponent who can time-travel, (<sup><sub>Future</sub></sup>)Picard would have ordered the *immediate* destruction of the portal, regardless of the damage it would have done to the timeline. (<sup><sub>Past</sub></sup>)Picard would have been aware of that and is trying to preserve the timeline as best as he can **by not giving (<sup><sub>Future</sub></sup>)Picard that knowledge until the time is right.**.

Knowing that La Forge hadn't conducted a diagnostic of Data's head before he left, (<sup><sub>Past</sub></sup>)Picard is gambling that his message to the future won't be heard until *after* his future self has gone through the portal but before Riker accidentally blows up the Earth.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chkzV_CVFW8

Comment: I can't find a clip of Picard programming the message, but I seem to remember Picard simply places whatever he's programming the message with inside of Data's head, rather than a separate piece of metal. It appears to be a nail of some sort on screen (which makes sense if you wish to poke around in there), but LaForge comments that it's an iron filing.

Comment: But one thing is very clear to me: I hate time travel plots.

Comment: @Ellesedil - at 00:36:35 you can see La Forge remove the filing. It's clearly very much smaller than the nail Picard was using.

Comment: @Ellesedil - 36 mins into [Time's Arrow, Part 2](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2d1auy_star-trek-the-next-generation-season-6-episode-01-time-s-arrow-part-2_tv)